# Behat + CircleCI Configuration for my drupal8 site

Tags: composer-php, behat, drupal-8, circleci, drush

I am very new to drupal. I am using drupal8 with pantheon. I have created a site "ucfictious". I have created a local copy by using composer and drush. Everything went well and I configured behat tests which also went well. Now I am trying to configure CircleCI through github. I ran into so many errors and I couldn't solve my errors. Can anyone help me with the configuration of CircleCI? I am using Craychee's Work to build CircleCI and When I run I get the following error:

**build/install.sh
Command config-import needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you        [error]
will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment
to run this command.
The drush command 'config-import' could not be executed.                 [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.             [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.**

*Drupal Version: 8.2.5
Drush Version: 8.1.8
Php Vesion: 5.6
For Behat Configuration I followed Craychee's work: http://craychee.io/blog/2015/08/04/no-excuses-part4-testing/*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Working...My database is not populated properly.....by doing a sql-sync from the DEV environment (so it was a known-clean copy, i.e. not filled with testing junk) and then used mysqldump.